# customCell image not responding on didSelectRowAtIndexPath (but otherwise works)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, cell

I have my a nice customCell for UITableView , all works well.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = nil;

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (CustomCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    // LOOK HERE: cellArrowPointingRight is an UIImage view of which I like to turn on later
    [cell.cellArrowPointingRight setHidden:YES];
    // The above line works as it hides all cellArrowPointingRight(s)

    return cell;
}
```

in the custom view (made in IB) I also have cellArrowPointingRight (it is connected to the H and @synthesize cellArrowPointingRight in the M

problem is that I can not run it on when selecting a cell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   // cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];
   cell.textLabel.text = @"Clicked";
  // PROBLEM HERE: (cellArrowPointingRight is not legal)
  [cell.cellArrowPointingRight setHidden:NO]; 
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

That default cell should not normally have a field called cellArrowPointingRight therefore a normal `UITableViewCell` would not respond to that.

What you need to do is to get the cell as :

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Assuming that your CustomCell is a superclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: terrific! thank you kindly. small question, assuming i want to circle all the cell and remove the image before I set it on a specific cell (which I pressed) , got a quick loop for me?

Comment: I did not clearly get your purpose? You want to loop through all the cells in the tableView and hide it for some specific cells?

Comment: it's ok, got it
for (int i=0; i<[items count]; i++) {
       CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        [cell.cellArrowPointingRight setHidden:YES]; 
    }

Thank again for your reply, you point me to the right way !

Comment: No problem, sometimes iterating owed row number can cause some problems you may iterate over indexPaths by getting all the indexPaths in the tableView and getting each cell by using
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
So you don't need to deal with sections or rows in this case.